# How to work with framebuffers in webgl?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have been trying to understand framebuffer in WebGL/OpenGL-ES.
I know that we can blend multiple textures using framebuffer.

So, to understand that I wrote a sample by taking a 1*1 texture and tried to apply framebuffer logic on top of it.
But , it didn't work.

See snippet at bottom, if you click on "mix red and blue", the images doesn't get rendered, am I doing anything wrong?

Code :
`

```
var canvas, gl, attrPosition, texture, program, vertexBuffer, textureBuffer, vertices, texVertices, attrPos, attrTexPos, textures = [], framebuffers = [];

canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    gl = getWebGL();
    vertices = new Float32Array([
        -1.0, -1.0,  
         1.0, -1.0, 
         1.0,  1.0, 
        -1.0,  1.0, 
        -1.0, -1.0, 
    ]);

    texVertices = new Float32Array([
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0
    ]);
    var getProgram = function () {
        var vs = createVertexShader([
            'attribute vec2 attrPos;',
            'attribute vec2 attrTexPos;',
            'varying highp vec2 vTexCoord;',
            'void main() {',
                '\tgl_Position = vec4(attrPos, 0.0, 1.0);',
            '}'
        ].join('\n'));

        var fs = createFragmentShader([
            'varying highp vec2 vTexCoord;',
            'uniform sampler2D uImage;',
            'void main() {',
                '\tgl_FragColor = texture2D(uImage, vTexCoord);',
            '}'
        ].join('\n'));
        return createAndLinkPrograms(vs, fs);
    };

    var render = function () {
        gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(attrPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, gl.FALSE, 0, 0);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(attrTexPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, gl.FALSE, 0, 0);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 5);
    };
    if (gl) {
        gl.clearColor(0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0);
        render();
        program = getProgram();
        texture = createAndSetupTexture();
        vertexBuffer = createAndBindBuffer(vertices, gl.ARRAY_BUFFER);
        attrPos = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'attrPos');
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attrPos);

        textureBuffer = createAndBindBuffer(texVertices, gl.ARRAY_BUFFER);
        attrTexPos = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'attrTexPos');
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attrTexPos);

        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([123, 0, 60, 255]));
        render();
    }

    var initPingPongTextures = function(textures, framebuffers) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            var tex = createAndSetupTexture(gl);
            textures.push(tex);
            // make the texture the same size as the image
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
            // Create a framebuffer
            var fbo = gl.createFramebuffer();
            framebuffers.push(fbo);
            gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
            // Attach a texture to it.
            gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
        }
    }

    var setFramebuffer = function(fbo, width, height) {
        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
        gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
    };

    var mixRedAndBlue = function () {
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        setFramebuffer(framebuffers[0], 1, 1);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([255, 0, 0, 255]));
        render();
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        setFramebuffer(framebuffers[1], 1, 1);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([0, 255, 0, 255]));
        render();
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);

        setFramebuffer(null, 1, 1);
        render();
    };`
```

```js
var getWebGLContext = function(canvas) {
 var webglContextParams = ['webgl', 'experimental-webgl', 'webkit-3d', 'moz-webgl'];
 var webglContext = null;
 for (var index = 0; index < webglContextParams.length; index++) {
  try {
   webglContext = canvas.getContext(webglContextParams[index]);
   if(webglContext) {
    //breaking as we got our context
    break;
   }
  } catch (E) {
   console.log(E);
  }
 }
 if(webglContext === null) {
  alert('WebGL is not supported on your browser.');
 } else {
  //WebGL is supported in your browser, lets render the texture
 }
 fillGLForCleanUp(webglContext);
 return webglContext;
}
var createVertexShader = function (vertexShaderSource) {
 console.log(vertexShaderSource);
 var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
 gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSource);
 gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
 return vertexShader;
}

var createFragmentShader = function (fragmentShaderSource) {
 console.log(fragmentShaderSource);
 var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
 gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSource);
 gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
 return fragmentShader;
}


var createAndLinkPrograms = function (vertexShader, fragmentShader) {
 var program = gl.createProgram();
 gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
 gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
 gl.linkProgram(program);
    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert('Could not initialise shaders');
    }
 gl.useProgram(program);
 return program;
}

var createAndBindBuffer = function (verticesOrIndices, bufferType) {
 var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
 gl.bindBuffer(bufferType, buffer);
 gl.bufferData(bufferType, verticesOrIndices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
 //clear memory
 gl.bindBuffer(bufferType, null);
 return buffer;
}

var allowAllImageSizes = function() {
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  // gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
} 

var createAndSetupTexture = function() {
 var texture = gl.createTexture();
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
 allowAllImageSizes();
 gl.textures.push(texture);
 return texture;
}

var getWebGL = function (canvas, width, height) {
 if(!canvas) {
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.id = 'canvas';
  canvas.width = !width ? 512 : width;
  canvas.height = !height ? 512 : height;
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
 } else {
  canvas.width = !width ? 512 : width;
  canvas.height = !height ? 512 : height;
 }
 return getWebGLContext(canvas);
}

var fillGLForCleanUp = function (gl) {
 gl.textures = [];
 gl.framebuffers = [];
 gl.array_buffer = [];
 gl.element_array_buffers = [];
}


var canvas, gl, attrPosition, texture, program, 
vertexBuffer, textureBuffer, vertices, texVertices,
attrPos, attrTexPos, textures = [], framebuffers = [];
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
gl = getWebGL(canvas);
vertices = new Float32Array([
 -1.0, -1.0,  
  1.0, -1.0, 
  1.0,  1.0, 
 -1.0,  1.0, 
 -1.0, -1.0, 
]);

texVertices = new Float32Array([
 0.0, 0.0,
 1.0, 0.0,
 1.0, 1.0,
 0.0, 1.0,
 0.0, 0.0
]);
var getProgram = function () {
 var vs = createVertexShader([
  'attribute vec2 attrPos;',
  'attribute vec2 attrTexPos;',
  'varying highp vec2 vTexCoord;',
  'void main() {',
   '\tgl_Position = vec4(attrPos, 0.0, 1.0);',
  '}'
 ].join('\n'));

 var fs = createFragmentShader([
  'varying highp vec2 vTexCoord;',
  'uniform sampler2D uImage;',
  'void main() {',
   '\tgl_FragColor = texture2D(uImage, vTexCoord);',
  '}'
 ].join('\n'));
 return createAndLinkPrograms(vs, fs);
};

var render = function () {
 gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(attrPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, gl.FALSE, 0, 0);
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(attrTexPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, gl.FALSE, 0, 0);
 gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 5);
};
if (gl) {
 gl.clearColor(0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0);
 render();
 program = getProgram();
 texture = createAndSetupTexture();
 vertexBuffer = createAndBindBuffer(vertices, gl.ARRAY_BUFFER);
 attrPos = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'attrPos');
 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attrPos);

 textureBuffer = createAndBindBuffer(texVertices, gl.ARRAY_BUFFER);
 attrTexPos = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'attrTexPos');
 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attrTexPos);

 gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([123, 0, 60, 255]));
 render();
}

var initPingPongTextures = function(textures, framebuffers) {
 for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
  var tex = createAndSetupTexture(gl);
  textures.push(tex);
  // make the texture the same size as the image
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
  // Create a framebuffer
  var fbo = gl.createFramebuffer();
  framebuffers.push(fbo);
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
  // Attach a texture to it.
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
 }
}

var setFramebuffer = function(fbo, width, height) {
 gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
 gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
};

var mixRedAndBlue = function () {
 gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

 setFramebuffer(framebuffers[0], 1, 1);
 gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([255, 0, 0, 255]));
 render();
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

 setFramebuffer(framebuffers[1], 1, 1);
 gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array([0, 255, 0, 255]));
 render();
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);

 setFramebuffer(null, 1, 1);
 render();
};
```

```html
<button id="redImg" onclick="mixRedAndBlue()">Mix Red and blue</button><hr/>
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

**Edit 1 :**

I am trying to achieve the same for multiple programs with multiple fragment shaders because having if/else statements within the fragment shader is not recommended as it runs for each pixel.

`
Shaders.prototype.VS_Base = [
            'attribute vec3 verticesPosition;',
            'attribute vec2 texturePosition;',
            'varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;',
            'void main(void) {',
            '\tgl_Position = vec4(verticesPosition * vec3(1.0, -1.0, 1.0), 0.5);',
            '\tvTextureCoord = texturePosition;',
            '}'
    ].join('\n');

```
Shaders.prototype.FS_Base_Image_RED = [
        '#ifdef GL_ES',
        'precision highp float;',
        '#endif',
        'uniform sampler2D uImage;',
        'varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;',
        'void main (void) {',
        '\tgl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);//texture2D(uImage, vTextureCoord);',
        '}'
].join('\n');

Shaders.prototype.FS_Base_Image_BLUE = [
        '#ifdef GL_ES',
        'precision highp float;',
        '#endif',
        'uniform sampler2D uImage;',
        'varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;',
        'void main (void) {',
        '\tgl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);//texture2D(uImage, vTextureCoord);',
        '}'
].join('\n');`
```

Now I have 2 separate programs for both the fragment shader and I need to use framebuffers for mixing Red and Blue. I am not looking for `mix()` as the actual scenario is very complex and that's the reason I am using multiple programs with fragment shaders for avoiding conditional if/else statements.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You've got one shader that only takes one texture as input. To mix 2 textures you need to have 2 textures as input.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do. Framebuffers are just a list of attachments (textures and renderbuffers). You use them to render to a texture and/or renderbuffer. Then you can use the texture you just rendered to as input to some other render.

Here's an example with NO framebuffers. It blends 2 textures.

```js
var vs = `
attribute vec4 position;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
  v_texcoord = position.xy * .5 + .5;
}
`;

var fs = `
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

uniform sampler2D tex1;
uniform sampler2D tex2;

void main() {
  vec4 color1 = texture2D(tex1, v_texcoord);
  vec4 color2 = texture2D(tex2, v_texcoord);
  gl_FragColor = mix(color1, color2, 0.5);
}
`;

const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
const program = twgl.createProgramFromSources(gl, [vs, fs]);

// make 2 textures with canvas 2d
const ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.canvas.width = 64;
ctx.canvas.height = 64;

// first texture has a circle
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 64, 64);
ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(32, 32, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.lineWidth = 12;
ctx.stroke();

const tex1 = createTextureFromCanvas(gl, ctx.canvas);

// second texture has a diamond (diagonal square)
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 64, 64);
ctx.fillStyle = "cyan";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(32, 6);
ctx.lineTo(58, 32);
ctx.lineTo(32, 58);
ctx.lineTo(6, 32);
ctx.lineTo(32, 6);
ctx.fill();

const tex2 = createTextureFromCanvas(gl, ctx.canvas);

const buf = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
  -1, -1,
   1, -1,
  -1,  1,
  -1,  1,
   1, -1,
   1,  1,
]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


const positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "position");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

const tex1Loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "tex1");  
const tex2Loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "tex2");  
  
gl.useProgram(program);

gl.uniform1i(tex1Loc, 0);
gl.uniform1i(tex2Loc, 1);
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex1);
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 1);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex2);

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

function createTextureFromCanvas(gl, canvas) {
  const tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, ctx.canvas);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  return tex;
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/2.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

For your purpose there is no difference about the blending part, the only difference is where the textures come from. Above the textures were created by using a 2d canvas. Instead you can use framebuffer to render to a texture. **AFTER** you've rendered to a texture you can then use that texture in some other render just like above.

To render to a texture first you create a framebuffer

```
var fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
```

Then you attach a texture to it

```
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);  
gl.framebufferTexture2D(
    gl.FRAMEBUFFER, 
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,  // attach texture as COLOR_ATTACHMENT0
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,         // attach a 2D texture
    someTexture,           // the texture to attach
    0);                    // the mip level to render to (must be 0 in WebGL1)
```

Depending on your attachments you should check if they work.

```
if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) !== gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
  // these attachments don't work
}
```

The WebGL spec lists 3 combinations of attachments that are guaranteed to work. The example below is using one of those 3 so there's no need to check

Now if you bind the framebuffer

```
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
```

Then when you call any `gl.drawXXX` function or `gl.clear` it will be drawing to the `someTexture` instead of the canvas. To start drawing to the canvas again bind `null`

```
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
```

Remember that if the canvas and the texture are different sizes you'll need to call `gl.viewport` to render correctly

```js
var vs = `
attribute vec4 position;

uniform mat4 matrix;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
  v_texcoord = position.xy * .5 + .5;
}
`;

var colorFS = `
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 color;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = color;
}
`;

var mixFS = `
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

uniform sampler2D tex1;
uniform sampler2D tex2;

void main() {
  // probably should use different texture coords for each
  // texture for more flexibility but I'm lazy
  vec4 color1 = texture2D(tex1, v_texcoord);
  vec4 color2 = texture2D(tex2, v_texcoord);
  gl_FragColor = mix(color1, color2, 0.5);
}
`;

const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
const colorProgram = twgl.createProgramFromSources(gl, [vs, colorFS]);
const mixProgram = twgl.createProgramFromSources(gl, [vs, mixFS]);

// make 2 textures by attaching them to framebuffers and rendering to them
const texFbPair1 = createTextureAndFramebuffer(gl, 64, 64);
const texFbPair2 = createTextureAndFramebuffer(gl, 64, 64);

const buf = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
  -1, -1,
   1, -1,
  -1,  1,
  -1,  1,
   1, -1,
   1,  1,
]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

function setAttributes(buf, positionLoc) {
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
}
  
const colorPrgPositionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(colorProgram, "position");
setAttributes(buf, colorPrgPositionLoc);
const colorLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(colorProgram, "color");
const colorProgMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(colorProgram, "matrix");

// draw red rect to first texture through the framebuffer it's attached to
gl.useProgram(colorProgram);
  
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, texFbPair1.fb);
gl.viewport(0, 0, 64, 64);
gl.uniform4fv(colorLoc, [1, 0, 0, 1]);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(colorProgMatrixLoc, false, [
  0.5, 0, 0, 0,
    0,.25, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
   .2,.3, 0, 1,
]);

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

// Draw a blue rect to the second texture through the framebuffer it's attached to
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, texFbPair2.fb);
gl.viewport(0, 0, 64, 64);
gl.uniform4fv(colorLoc, [0, 0, 1, 1]);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(colorProgMatrixLoc, false, [
  0.25, 0, 0, 0,
    0,.5, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
   .2,.3, 0, 1,
]);

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

// Draw both textures to the canvas
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  
const mixPrgPositionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(mixProgram, "position");
setAttributes(buf, mixPrgPositionLoc);
  
const mixProgMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(mixProgram, "matrix");

const tex1Loc = gl.getUniformLocation(mixProgram, "tex1");  
const tex2Loc = gl.getUniformLocation(mixProgram, "tex2");  
  
gl.useProgram(mixProgram);

gl.uniform1i(tex1Loc, 0);
gl.uniform1i(tex2Loc, 1);
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texFbPair1.tex);
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 1);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texFbPair2.tex);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(mixProgMatrixLoc, false, [
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1,
]);  

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

function createTextureAndFramebuffer(gl, width, height) {
  const tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(
     gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
  return {tex: tex, fb: fb};
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/2.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

The only functional difference between the first program and the second is how the textures got their data. In the first example the textures got their data from a canvas 2d. In the 2nd example the textures got their data by rendering to them using WebGL.

As for why your example doesn't blend textures, in order to blend 2 textures you need a shader that uses two textures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I have multiple programs and each program has a separate fragment shader and common vertex shader. I am trying to pass output from one fragment shader to another fragment shader in another program. Can you please modify your answer to support multiple programs or assist me with some pseudocode

Comment: A fragment shader outputs to either the canvas or the attachments in a framebuffer. To be more terse a fragment shader outputs to a texture (internally to WebGL a canvas is really a framebuffer with a texture attachment). To use the output of one fragment shader in another shader you just use the texture you wrote to in the first fragment shader as input into the second fragment shader (is in in the second fragment shader you make a `uniform sampler2D` and assign it the texture you wrote to when you rendered with the first fragment shader.

Comment: So, you mean to say I can achieve this without using framebuffers ? Or I will definitely need the framebuffers. Because I don't know how to pass the output of one fs to another fs..

Comment: The second example already does what you're asking. It creates 2 programs `colorProgram` and `mixProgram`. It uses `colorProgram` to write to `gl_FragColor` which because we called `gl.bindFrambuffer(texFbPair1.fb)` writes to pixels in `texFbPair1.tex` texture because `texFbPair1.tex` is attached to `texFbPair1.fb` framebuffer. Then the same shader is used with `gl.bindFramebuffer(..., texFbPair2.fb)` to write to `texFBPair2.tex`. Finally both of those textures are passed to `mixProgram` as normal textures.

Comment: You need the framebuffers. By attaching a texture to a framebuffer and then binding that framebuffer you're making the shader write to the texture. You can then use that texture with other shaders just like any normal texture.

Comment: Got it thanks , I can now understand how framebuffer works. :)